# Writing structured json log messages from Python Google Cloud Function

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

I've tried using [this example code from the Cloud Functions docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#writing_structured_logs):

```py
# PROJECT = 'The project ID of your Cloud Run service';
global_log_fields = {}
trace_header = request.headers.get('X-Cloud-Trace-Context')
trace = trace_header.split('/')
global_log_fields['logging.googleapis.com/trace'] = (
    f"projects/{PROJECT}/traces/{trace[0]}")
entry = dict(severity='NOTICE',
             message='This is the default display field.',
             # Log viewer accesses 'component' as jsonPayload.component'.
             component='arbitrary-property',
             **global_log_fields)
print(json.dumps(entry))
```

In the Log Explorer, the corresponding logged items look something like:

```
{
textPayload: "{"severity": "NOTICE", "message": "This is the default display field.", "component": "arbitrary-property", "logging.googleapis.com/trace": "projects/[...]/traces/abaa6a6d18e3dd498347c43ad9137d0b"}"
insertId: "[...]"
resource: {[...]}
timestamp: "2020-11-20T17:39:45.613Z"
severity: "INFO"
labels: {[...]}
logName: "projects/[...]/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions"
trace: "projects/[...]/traces/abaa6a6d18e3dd498347c43ad9137d0b"
receiveTimestamp: "2020-11-20T17:39:55.906103427Z"
}
```

The main issue being that the json representation is stuffed into the `textPayload` field rather than showing up in `jsonPayload` in structured form.

It's also interesting that the `trace` value on the log item seems to be automagically set already, suggesting there's no need for me to read the `'X-Cloud-Trace-Context'` header on the request. (I confirmed that the trace value is definitely not being read from my json payload. It still appears if I remove the `logging.googleapis.com/trace` field from the logged dictionary.)

Comment: Did you try to add the timestamp inside the JSON? I think it's a missing piece of FluentD format.

Comment: Hey :) great question btw, did you find any solution ?  i'm facing the same problem as you.

Comment: I've opened an issue here to see if there's a follow up https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/5036